# Swiper doesn't find useEffect from React in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

I'm having issues integrating Swiper into my NextJS project. I've created a component with a basic Swiper configuration (the one in the docs) but it fails to find `useEffect` from `React` when included in an already working page. If I remove the component, everything works as expected.

The error is the following:

```
SyntaxError: The requested module 'react' does not provide an export named 'useEffect'
```

And the call stack points to this file:

```
file:///[...]/<project_root>/node_modules/swiper/react/use-isomorphic-layout-effect.js
```

Swiper.js (My component)

```js
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

import 'swiper/css';

export default () => {
  return (
    <Swiper
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={3}
      onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
      onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      ...
    </Swiper>
  );
};
```

use-isomorphic-layout-effect.js (File failing to find `useEffect`)

```js
import { useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

function useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(callback, deps) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return useEffect(callback, deps);
  return useLayoutEffect(callback, deps);
}

export { useIsomorphicLayoutEffect };
```

It's a NextJS (12.1.6) using React (18.1.0) and Swiper (^8.3.0). ES Modules are used by default. `useEffect` is used multiple times in the project, so it definitely exists in the project. I also tried to activate ES Modules Support from NextJS (https://nextjs.org/blog/next-11-1#es-modules-support) but didn't work.

I've been looking through the Internet for a solution, but couldn't find anything useful for this specific issue. I've been also trying to use direct imports to the Swiper files but couldn't make it work either.

Any idea what could be happening? I'm sure I'm missing a basic piece here but cannot get my head around it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've installed nvm on my sistem and switched to node version 16. Before I had node version 14. And this error gone.

Somehow It looks like that installing some dependencies with not compatible version of nodejs and react is pain in the bass :)